# "fatal error" while running phpmyadmin on readynas duo

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

im new to this forum but have searched for similar questions with no appropriate solution. I have a readynas duo (sparc with latest OS from netgear) and installed the php and phpmyadmin add-ons by "who cares?"  (http://rnxtras.com/addons/category/readynas-os4-sparc)
All options came checked in php add on and i have not edited anything. while phpmyadmin lets me use its configure server option, it does not let me use the "use phpmyadmin" link. there are only two links in the phpmyadmin add on that one can choose (use and configure). I did follow the included configure server steps. But no matter what I did, the use option always leads to the same error below in the web-browser. I have no experience with php or mysql in command line.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function PMA_DBI_num_rows() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/navigation/Nodes/Node.class.php on line 408
```

mysql and mysqli are both checked in the php add-on options. I am trying to do this all over a local network. i re-installed the addons, ssh is enabled. no luck. I cannot find any help on this. please help. I have never worked with php and want to use it to simply build a mysql database for my work, hopefully using phpmyadmin installed on my readynas duo v1. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a package which contains the mysql or mysqli PHP extensions (preferably mysqli). Starting with version 4.0.7, phpMyAdmin shows a proper error message for this situation, see https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3997/.